# Invalid Argument WebForm

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

I'm getting two error messages:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in wf_crm_get_fields() (line 910 of /home3/site/public_html/sites/all/modules/webform_civicrm/includes/utils.inc).

Notice: Undefined index: caseRoles in wf_crm_get_fields() (line 910 of /home3/site/public_html/sites/all/modules/webform_civicrm/includes/utils.inc).

when I try to enter information on Drupal 7 using a webform.

What could be causing this issue? Is there a way that I can work around this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see -> [What is the recommended/supported version of Webform CiviCRM module for Drupal 7?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/36180/what-is-the-recommended-supported-version-of-webform-civicrm-module-for-drupal-7)

First step would be to move to the supported version for D7WFC -> 7.x-5.x

Your error message tells me you're on 7.x-4.x
https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/blob/7.x-4.x/includes/utils.inc#L910

Comment: How would I go about updating the Webform since I don't have Drush / Composer. I tried to update, however, in Drupal there is no option to update it.

Comment: If you have access you can probably also sftp it over and into your sites/default/modules

Comment: I realize that, however, I'm getting the follwong message: ge Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in wf_crm_get_fields() (line 954 of /home3/isrcus/public_html/sites/all/modules/webform_civicrm/includes/utils.inc). (I Just updated the module)

Comment: You can file an issue on https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm - however and in the mean time you should really switch throwing notices to: None on your admin/config/development/logging if this is a live site.

Comment: Will do, thank you for your help.